# Appium Error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

While executing java program in Appium on real device through Remote control I'm getting error on Appium server as 0 device connected even though my device is connected & also in console it shows exception like

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable USB Debugging on your device. After that you should be able to see it in the ADB device list.
For more details read the [How to execute test on real android devices](https://nishantverma.gitbooks.io/appium-for-android/executing_test_on_real_devices/).